# React: Reusable components design pattern

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, reusability

I have 3 similar forms and i can't understand should i make h1, divider, link reusable if they are in every form but with different labels. Thanks.

**Here, is my code:**

```js
    <>
      <Form id="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Sign in to SyncTalk</h1> // this title
        <GoogleButton label="Sign in" />
        <Divider className="divider">or</Divider> // this divider
        <div className="input-container">
          <StyledTextField
            type="email"
            name="email"
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="error" /> // this
        </div>
        <div className="nav">
          <FormButton label="Send link" />
          <div className="to-sign-in">
            Don't have an account?
            <Link href="/sign-up">Sign up</Link> // this link
          </div>
        </div>
      </Form>
      <Alert alertLabel={alertLabel} />
    </>;
```

Comment: If you're only using this for 2-3 times, than I feel you don't need to create separate component for h1, divider and Link tags. However, If you're planning to use all these tags in various components, than you can define them as a separate component. Thanks.